# Trouble getting data from doInBackground

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

I had issues with my code working as the UI thread was doing to much work. I had to make a Async task to fetch the JSON data.

my problem is that I can not fetch the data from my class that has all my getters and setters in. I am new to Android Development.

```
public class LoadPoliceData extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,Void>{

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Map");
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(URL... urls) {

                //TODO: don't fetch twice could cause bug
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
                double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");

                String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
                String lng = String.valueOf(longitude);

                String URL = API_URL;
                Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(URL).buildUpon();
                builder.appendQueryParameter("lat", lat);
                builder.appendQueryParameter("lng",lng);
                URL =builder.build().toString();

                Log.d(TAG, "buildURL: " + URL);

                if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL)){

                    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try{
                                for (int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){



                                    JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    policeUkApi newModel = new policeUkApi();
                                    newModel.setCategory(data.getString("category"));
                                    JSONObject latlng= data.getJSONObject("location");

                                    newModel.setLatitude(latlng.getDouble("latitude"));
                                    newModel.setLongitude(latlng.getDouble("longitude"));


                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    });
                    mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

                }else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "ERROR GET API DATA URL NOT VALID");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
                markerOptions.title(newModel.getCategory());
                markerOptions.snippet(newModel.getDate());
                markerOptions.position(new LatLng(newModel.getLatitude(),newModel.getLongitude()));

                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
```

Error I get is

[image]

I am missing some or forgetting some lessons I have learned it would be use full if you have any links regarding the theory

Comment: You defined `policeUkApi newModel = new policeUkApi();` inside `onResponse()` method and trying to get data in other method `onPostExecute()`. Not possible.

Comment: There is no real need for a Background thread (unless the response you are parsing is very large) because `JsonArrayRequest ` triggers an async transaction and the result will appear in `onResponse()` when it is ready.

Comment: what would you define as "Very Large"

Comment: I would not feel comfortable advising to parse more than 50 entries in your loop without knowing more about the data. To reiterate: `JsonArrayRequest` is already Asynchronous with the result appearing in `onResponse()`. However, any code or loop you provide in `onResponse()` will be handled on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this modified class according to your need,

```java
public class LoadPoliceData extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,policeUkApi> {
    private policeUkApi newModel=new policeUkApi();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Map");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected policeUkApi doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        //TODO: don't fetch twice could cause bug
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        double latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
        double longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");

        String lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String lng = String.valueOf(longitude);

        String URL = API_URL;
        Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(URL).buildUpon();
        builder.appendQueryParameter("lat", lat);
        builder.appendQueryParameter("lng",lng);
        URL =builder.build().toString();

        Log.d(TAG, "buildURL: " + URL);

        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(URL)){

            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try{
                        for (int i = 0; i<response.length();i++){



                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            newModel.setCategory(data.getString("category"));
                            JSONObject latlng= data.getJSONObject("location");

                            newModel.setLatitude(latlng.getDouble("latitude"));
                            newModel.setLongitude(latlng.getDouble("longitude"));


                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            });
            mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR GET API DATA URL NOT VALID");
        }

        return newModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(policeUkApi newModel) {
        super.onPostExecute(newModel);
        if(newModel!=null){

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            markerOptions.title(newModel.getCategory());
            markerOptions.snippet(newModel.getDate());
            markerOptions.position(new LatLng(newModel.getLatitude(),newModel.getLongitude()));

            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }
}
```

Let's give a brief explanation of how AsyncTask works,

```java
AsyncTask<InputParamType, ProgressUpdateParamType, OutputParamType>
```

In this example, URL = InputParamType, which is an input to the background method **doInBackGround(URL... urls)**

Void = Progress Param type, since we are not updating the progress.

policeUkApi = output custom class type that you already defined, and this is the return type of doInBackground(...) which runs in the background thread.

When you return the result, in this case, your custom class policeUkApi, it is the input of the method **onPostExecute(..)** which also runs in UI thread and you can update your ui from there.

**onPreExecute()** also runs on UI thread.

Comment: Why put `JsonArrayRequest()` in an AsyncTask?  `JsonArrayRequest()` is already Asynchronous!

Comment: @Barns, I have not even looked at the code inside the doInBackground, the primary question here is how the asynctask works and how can we update the data that we get in doInBackground in the UI thread. He is new to development and I discussed about how asynctasks work

Comment: I am getting error that app was skipping to many frames so I assumed it what this causing the problem

Comment: @NoobAndroid, if you are doing a lot of task in the UI thread, yes that will cause the app to perform poor. Since you're using Volley, the json array request itself runs in a background thread and displays the result in onResponse.

Comment: Only things I have got

is a map/ A getlaglong function where/ and  fetch this data

Comment: If you are testing in an emulator and getting a few frames skipped, I won't worry too much about that, but if it's a lot of frames and happening in real device as well, then that's a problem.  If you're using google map, that's also loaded in background and returns when the map is ready in onMapReady